# How to reference allauth user as foreign key in Django

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

If I use normal `user` provided django default, my model will be like this.

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import Users

class Photo(models.Model):
    photographer=models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user') # 5
    # other fields
```

If I want to implement `allauth`, what should I have to pass for the first argument in line#5, instead of User?

Comment: ```from django.contrib.auth.models import Users``` is wrong it's ```User``` not ```Users```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django-allauth still uses the User model from django's auth, so you don't have to change anything. Unless you've extended a custom user model.